# Deducing register contents through IDA scripting

Tags: ida, idapython

In some of my IDA scripts, it would be useful to be able to reason about which variables were stored in which registers at a given place in the program. One example is the following:

`mov     rdx, [rbp+client]
mov     rax, [rbp+channel]
mov     rsi, rdx
mov     rdi, rax
call    sub_41002D`

It would be useful if I could deduce that, at the time when sub_41002D is called, rdi contains the variable called "channel" and rsi contains the variable "client".

Is there any IDA scripting feature which allows me to do this, or will I need to roll my own solution? If so, is there a name for what I'm trying to do? Do algorithms for this already exist? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: There was a user who wanted to do something similar, but not for IDA, a while ago. I'm not aware of anything existing like this for IDA, and the neccesary algorithms and data structures might be a bit complex for IDA's `idc` language, but my answer to [that question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/il-for-decompiler-to-human-readable-format/8838?s=1|0.2307#8838) might give you some ideas.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm thank you for the pointer. I was planning on using IDAPython.